# How to render an element and pass it to a json data view in CakePHP

Tags: php, json, cakephp

I'm currently upgrading one of my latest apps to cakePHP 2.3 and it contains of a lot of JavaScript/AJAX stuff.

I have the following code:

```
function do_stuff() {
  $html_content = $this->render('/elements/my_element');
  $status = 'success';

  $this->set('html_content', $html_content);
  $this->set('status', $status);

  $this->set('_serialize', array('html_content', 'status'));
}
```

I call the function by AJAX with https://mydomain.tld/controller/do_stuff.json

Of course, I would like to receive a JSON object with { 'html_content': '…', 'status': 'success' },

but I'm receiving only the html_content. I think, it's due to the $this->render() call.

Anyone having a hint/solution for this problem?

Comment: Why are you trying to render twice, instead of just rending `/json/do_stuff.json` and in that view rendering your element?

Comment: i need the json structure to have status set to success. the above code is, of course, simplified. it's also possible, that status returns 'error', and then i won't display the html_content.

i know, that the code is not perfect, but first of all, i have to migrate cakephp properly. second task is to refactor logic :)

Comment: Your comment doesn't answer my question

Comment: yeah, you're right. i thought about it a second time and found the following solution:

pass the elementname as $html_content to the view and do a json_encode(array('status' => $status, 'html_content' => $this->element($html_content)) there.

works, but is not perfect, i guess :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know whether it is hack or good code. but this worked perfectly fine on running  CakePHP 2.3

```
function do_stuff() {

  // modified below two lines
  $this->View = $this->_getViewObject();
  $html_content = $this->View->render('/Elements/main_menu');

  $status = 'success';

  $this->set('html_content', $html_content);
  $this->set('status', $status);

  $this->set('_serialize', array('html_content', 'status'));
}
```

Comment: This is my first answer that was accepted.This is nice to know this worked for you. Cheers.

Comment: The code doesn't returns any response. How would i get it in Jquery ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to render a view in another place (EventListener, Model, Controller...), you can do the following :

```php
$View = new View();
$html_content = $View->element('/Elements/main_menu', array(
    'foo'=>'bar'
));
```

Then, you can serialize your html content.